# Ignore SSL certificate in .Net Standard 2.0

Tags: c#, .net, ssl, xamarin.forms, .net-standard-2.0

I am creating a Xamarin Cross Platform Application in it, I have replaced the Portable Class Library with **.Net Standard 2.0**. From this project we are making a call to web service hosted on azure service fabric cluster (this service is hosted using self signed certificate).I am
getting the following error while making a connection request -

> InnerException    {System.Runtime.InteropServices.COMException
>   (0x80072F0D): The text associated with this error code could not be
>   found.
>
> The certificate authority is invalid or incorrect
>
> at System.Runtime.ExceptionServices.ExceptionDispatchInfo.Throw()
>   at
>   System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task
>   task)    at
>   System.Net.Http.HttpHandlerToFilter.d__15.MoveNext()
>   --- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---    at
>   System.Runtime.ExceptionServices.ExceptionDispatchInfo.Throw()    at
>   System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task
>   task)    at
>   System.Net.Http.DiagnosticsHandler.d__2.MoveNext()
>   --- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---    at
>   System.Runtime.ExceptionServices.ExceptionDispatchInfo.Throw()    at
>   System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task
>   task)    at
>   System.Net.Http.HttpClientHandler.d__111.MoveNext()}   System.Exception
>   {System.Runtime.InteropServices.COMException}

I think the self-signed SSL causing the problem, in general in order to bypass certificate we use following code snippet

```
ServicePointManager.ServiceCertificateValidationCallback += (o, c, ch, er) => true;
```

And it works for Console Application targeting .Net framework 4.6.1 but this code doesn't seem to work for .Net Standard 2.0 and .Net Core 2.0 apps.
Do we have to do something different in order to bypass certificates in .Net Standard and .Net Core apps.
Following is the sample code area that is producing this error

```
IHubProxy _hub;
string url = @"https://www.xyz:com:8080/";
var connection = new HubConnection(url);
_hub = connection.CreateHubProxy("MyHub");
connection.Start().Wait();
```

Comment: I had to do a double take, but this is not a repost of [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/47433527/4137916), although the underlying issue is likely the same.

Answer (score 1):

ServicePointManager is not available in .NET Core, but you should be able to set a custom delegate using the HttpClientHandler.ServerCertificateCustomValidationCallback property using System.Net.Http 4.1+.

See [Add support for custom validation of server SSL Certificate to HttpClient API](https://github.com/dotnet/corefx/issues/4476) and [System.Net.Http 4.1 Contract Revisions](https://github.com/dotnet/corefx/issues/7623) on dotnet/corefx GitHub.

Answer (score 1):

You can simply write this in your platform specific projects like in Main Activity / App Delegate:

```
ServicePointManager.ServerCertificateValidationCallback +=
     (sender, cert, chain, sslPolicyErrors) => true;
```

Comment: Working perfectly for Xamarin.Android with a netstandard2 Xamarin.Forms project ! Thanks.
NB. You should add this into MainActivity.OnCreate()

Comment: Not working for Xamarin.Forms 3.2.0.839982 trying to connect a secured API using ASP.NET Core 2.1